# Getting rows that are not present in table

Tags: mysql

I two tables

```
product_categories
------------------
id PK AUTO
category

store_product_categories
------------------------
id PK AUTO
store_id FK
category FK (product_categories id)
```

Now what I want to get the rows that are NOT in store_product_categories

This is the query I designed but gives me no result

```
 SELECT * FROM store_product_categories spc 
     LEFT JOIN product_categories pc
     on spc.category=pc.id 
     WHERE spc.store_id=23 AND pc.id IS NULL
```

Comment: The query looks correct, are you sure you have data for which there should be any result?

Comment: add example values for both tables in your question

Comment: you've an answer below now. If that doesn't solve it, then my first comment applies

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nothing wrong with using a `LEFT JOIN` IMO.  Let's see what the actual data is.

Comment: you are using `WHERE spc.store_id=23 AND pc.id IS NULL`. maybe remove?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.  You claim to want rows *not in* `store_product_categories` and yet you are selecting from that table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Um... I didn't say there was anything wrong with using LEFT JOIN *lol* why the comment about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot select from  `store_product_categories` *and* get rows that are not in that table.  So, I speculate that you want *categories* that are not in the table:

```
SELECT pc.*
FROM product_categories pc LEFT JOIN
     store_product_categories spc 
     ON spc.category = pc.id AND spc.store_id = 23 
WHERE spc.category IS NULL;
```

Note that `spc_store_id = 23` is in the `ON` clause because the condition is on the second table.

Comment: This query is working! Thank you for explanation too! And yess that is exactly what I wanted. Thank you:)